# Fridge works for 2 months if I unplug it for 2 hours

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator

My fridge quits working after a couple months. The only fix seems to be unplugging it for a few hours then plugging it back in.

It is not iced over.

I have replaced the main control board.

I have replaced the compressor inverter board.

Each fix fixes it for 2 months (presumably because it involves removing power for a decent amount of time). Then it quits cooling again.

It is a Kenmore Elite all digital. No defrost timer (part of main control board). Temp gauges read out current temp on digital display (that's actually how I know it's stopping cooling as these readings creep up).

Comment: Have the coils been cleaned? It's tenuous but is it possible that its just getting gunked up every other month and when you're back unplugging it it gets wiped down?

Comment: Is any component running hotter than normal? Any burned contacts?

Comment: Yes I cleaned it and inspect fans for motion/noise. It was dirty but cleaning seemed to have no effect. When I unplug it to "fix" it, no cleaning occurs in this time. Just unplug, wait, plug in.

Comment: I have not seen or smelled any burned connections or components of any sort. Nothing seems to be running especially hot but I don't typically feel the temp of various components for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Side-by-side or top/bottom?

When this happens do you get high temp on refrigerator, freezer or both?

Some side-by-side refrigerators have a vent between the two sections which can ice up - in which case my guess is you would see different effects on each side. A couple of hours might be enough for that to melt and then everything works fine for a while.

Comment: Side by side. The freezer temp starts going up first, then the fridge does as well. Eventually they both end up in the 60s.

Comment: I've got a Kenmore (a bit older, but not ancient) and it has two vents between the refrigerator and freezer, one on top and on bottom. If either one is blocked then things don't work right.

Comment: Hmm. 60s seems a bit high for the vent to be stay frozen, so it is likely something else.